# Drag and Drop with ImageView

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I am currently on a project using Drag and Drop in Android. What I want to accomplish is, (as seen on the link below) I'll drag the mushroom to the pizza dough then, when I drop it, my ready made picture of mushrooms will be seen together with the pizza dough. I've made the code already but I am not sure about it. For the mushroom, I used a button and for the pizza dough, I used an ImageView. I've tried running it but every time I run it, it has the message "Unfortunately, your app has stopped"

[please see image for clearer understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lxd99.jpg)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button b1, b2, b3;
// TextView txt; //
ImageView image;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    // txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView); //
    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);


    b1.setOnLongClickListener(longClickListener);
    b2.setOnLongClickListener(longClickListener);
    b3.setOnLongClickListener(longClickListener);

    image.setOnDragListener(dragListener);
}

View.OnLongClickListener longClickListener = new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("","");
        View.DragShadowBuilder myShadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v);
        v.startDrag(data,myShadowBuilder,v,0);
        return true;
    }
};

View.OnDragListener dragListener = new View.OnDragListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        int dragEvent = event.getAction();

        final View view = (View) event.getLocalState();

        switch(dragEvent){
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:

                if (view.getId() == R.id.button){
                    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.pepperoni);
                }

                else if (view.getId() == R.id.button1){
                    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.mushrooms);
                }

                else if (view.getId() == R.id.button2){
                    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.pineapples);
                }
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                if (view.getId() == R.id.button){
                    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.pizzadough);
                }

                else if (view.getId() == R.id.button1){
                    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.pizzadough);
                }

                else if (view.getId() == R.id.button2){
                    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.pizzadough);
                }
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                if (view.getId() == R.id.button){
                    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.pepperoni);
                }

                else if (view.getId() == R.id.button1){
                    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.mushrooms);
                }

                else if (view.getId() == R.id.button2){
                    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.pineapples);
                }
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }
};
```

}

Comment: So - this code is working? But you want to know if it's good?

Comment: I've tried running it but every time I run it, it has the message "Unfortunately, your app has stopped"

Comment: OK... I suggest you add that to the question. If you have a logcat, you should add that to. You can use the "edit" link below your post, to edit this into your question. With the logcat, people will be better able to find the source of the problem.

Comment: post your logcat?

Comment: @S.L.Barth, thank you for guiding me. I will.

Comment: @S.L.Barth, wait a sec, I've tried running it now and it worked.

Comment: Well, congrats, I guess! You seem to have fixed it.